# Precise definition of limits and $\lim_{x\to-1}\frac1{\sqrt{x^2+3}}=\frac12$

Tags: calculus, limits, epsilon-delta

> Prove using the epsilon-delta definition,
>   $$
> \lim_{x\to-1}\frac1{\sqrt{x^2+3}}=\frac12
> $$

what I came up so far was:

$0<|x+1|<δ$ implies $\left|\frac1{\sqrt{x^2+3}} - \frac12\right|<ϵ$

\begin{align}
&\frac1{\sqrt{x^2+3}} - \frac12 \\
&=\frac{2\sqrt{x^2+3}-(x^2+3)}{2(x^2+3)} \\
&= \frac{2\sqrt{(x+1)^2-2(x+1)+4} - ((x+1)^2-2(x+1)+4)}{2[(x+1)^2-2(x+1)+4]} 
\end{align}

I'm unable to proceed because there are no real roots for $y^2-2y+4$

Can some please help me with this question? Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Easier method to prove limit by epsilon delta definition.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1453296/easier-method-to-prove-limit-by-epsilon-delta-definition)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps it is not the best idea to make the denominator square free
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+3}}-\frac12 
&= \frac{2-\sqrt{x^2+3}}{2\sqrt{x^2+3}}=\frac{4-(x^2+3)}{2\sqrt{x^2+3}(2+\sqrt{x^2+3})}
\\
&=\frac{(1-x)(1+x)}{2\sqrt{x^2+3}(2+\sqrt{x^2+3})}
\end{align}
using binomial formulas twice.

Comment: Thanks @LutzL! But may I know how did you get from the second term to the third and the third to the fourth? Sorry I'm not familiar with binomial formulas!

Comment: Use $a^2-b^2=(a-b)(a+b)$ resp. $a-b=(a^2-b^2)/(a+b)$, i.e., expand the fraction with the factor $(2+\sqrt{x^2+3})$.

Comment: Thanks so much! I was able to solve it with your prompt :)