# Easier method to prove limit by epsilon delta definition.

Tags: calculus, limits, epsilon-delta

supposed I wish to prove this limit via the epsilon delta definition of limits:

$$\lim_{x \to -1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+3}}=\frac{1}{2}.$$

This means I have to show that:

$$\bigg|\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+3}} - \frac{1}{2}\bigg| < \epsilon$$ 
whenever $0<\big|x +1\big|<\delta$.

How can I proceed to choose $\delta$ in a way such that my proof will be simple? So far I have tried to work "backwards" but ended up all messy because of the squareroot.

Any hint or help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\varepsilon > 0$; then
$$
\begin{split} \left| \frac{1}{(x^{2}+3)^{1/2}} - \frac{1}{2}\right| &= \left| \frac{2 - (x^{2}+3)^{1/2}}{2(x^{2}+3)^{1/2}}\right| \\
&= \frac{|x-1||x+1|}{4(x^{2}+3)^{1/2} + 2(x^{2}+3)} \\
&< |x-1||x+1| \\
&< |x+1| \\
&< \varepsilon
\end{split}$$
if $|x+1| < 3$ and $< \varepsilon$,
so taking $\delta := \min \{ 3, \varepsilon \}$ suffices.

Comment: Hi may I ask how does the |x+1|<3 come into play here? I can see why you need to take |x+1|< epsilon.

Comment: @thedilated: $3$ is taken simply for convenience here; note that $\delta := \min \{ 3, \varepsilon \}$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\left|\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+3}}-\frac{1}{2}\right|=\frac{|2-\sqrt{x^2+3}|}{2\sqrt{x^2+3}}=\frac{\left|2-|x|\sqrt{1+\frac{3}{x^2}}\right|}{2\sqrt{x^2+3}}$$

Take $-2\leq x\leq 0$, then

you can easily show that 
$$\left|2-|x|\sqrt{1+\frac{3}{x^2}}\right|\leq |x+1|$$

and conclude.